# react+redux how can son component get props?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

this is my code:
**action:**
`const increaseAction = { type: 'increase' }`
**reducer:**

```
  // Reducer
  function counter(state = { count: 0 }, action) {
    const count = state.count
    switch (action.type) {
    ┊ case 'increase':
    ┊ ┊ return { count: count + 1 }
    ┊ default:
    ┊ ┊ return state
    }
  }
```

this is my Store:
`const store = createStore(counter)`
**and others:**

```
  // Map Redux state to component props
  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log(33333);
    return {
    ┊ value: state.count
    }
  }

  // Map Redux actions to component props
  function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
    ┊ onIncreaseClick: () => {
    ┊ ┊ console.log(22222222222);
    ┊ ┊ dispatch(increaseAction)
    ┊ }
    }
  }

  // Connected Component
  const App = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(Main)


  ReactDOM.render(
    ┊ <Provider store={store}>
    ┊ ┊ <App />
    ┊ </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('content')
  );
```

**My Main component: **

```
>>class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    ┊ super(props);
    }
    render() {
      const {value, onIncreaseClick} = this.props;
    ┊ return (
    ┊ ┊ <div className={reactRootClass}>
    ┊ ┊ ┊ <div className='trade-left' onClick={onIncreaseClick}>
    ┊ ┊ ┊ </div>
    ┊ ┊ ┊ <div className='trade-right'>
    ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ <Counter />
    ┊ ┊ ┊ </div>
    ┊ ┊ </div>
    ┊ )
    }
  }
```

and this is my question:
now, I can call `onIncreaseClick` on `<div className='trade-left' onClick={onIncreaseClick}>`

now I want call `onIncreaseClick` in my `<Counter />` component, how can I get `value` and `onIncreaseClick` like in `<Main>` component? with `props`?
and this is my `<Counter>` component:

```
>>import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
  export default class Counter extends Component {
    render() {
    ┊ const { value, onIncreaseClick } = this.props
    ┊ return (
    ┊ ┊ <div>
    ┊ ┊ ┊ <span>{value}</span>
    ┊ ┊ ┊ <button onClick={onIncreaseClick}>Increase</button>
    ┊ ┊ </div>
    ┊ )
    }
  }
```

I just want to call `onIncreaseClick` in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass down peice of state (to children's) via MapStateToProps method ,similarly you can pass down actions to children's via mapDispatchToProps function like below :

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  const {updateData} = importedActions;
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators({updateData}, dispatch),
  };
}
```

This the way containers communicated with all the children's component in hierarchy

Comment: sorry, i can't understand, how can I get func in children's component? can you give me some code?

Comment: look over the tuts and undersatnf how MapDispatchToProps works ->http://blog.krawaller.se/posts/a-react-redux-example-app/ or watch egghead videos --> https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-using-mapdispatchtoprops-shorthand-notation